# Why do i get an infinite loop in my while loop with a nested if statement?

Tags: java

I have been working on the Percolation problem that some of you may have encountered before. You open up sites in a grid and once water can flow through consecutive open sites, the system percolates. In the PercolationStats file, you create a grid of size NxN and open sites at random until it percolates. You store how many sites it took to percolate and you run the experiment T times. Once you have finished all T experiments, you output the average number of times you needed to open sites at random before the grid percolated.

I am almost done but now my loop is stuck
What's interesting is that it is only stuck if N > 1. If N = 1, then the program runs properly.

I've tried a lot of random ideas like changing the inputs inside StdRandom (1, N+1) or (1, N). I've also tried switching lines of code around inside the loop, outside the loop, etc.

```
    public New_PercolationStats(int N, int T) {
    if (N <= 0 || T <= 0) 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    t = T;
    int sites = 0;
    int open = 0;
    results = new double[t];
    for (int x = 0; x < t; x++) {
        percolation = new New_Percolation(N);
        while(!percolation.percolates()) {
            int i = StdRandom.uniform(0, N);
            int j = StdRandom.uniform(0, N);
            int k = StdRandom.uniform(1, 4);
            open++;

            if (percolation.isOpen(i, j) == false) {
                percolation.open(i, j, k);
                sites++;
            }
        }
        double result = (double) sites / (N * N);
        results[x] = result;
        }
    }
```

I want the while loop to continue into the if statement if the site (i, j) is not open and I want it to open site (i, j) by inputting a value k which can range between 1 and 3. However, when I run the code I am constantly running the while loop and never entering the if statement.

Comment: What defined when `percolation.percolates()` returns `true`? Have you ensured that it's not buggy?

Comment: I notice you never update `percolation` in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If it's stuck in the `while` loop, the issue must be that `percolation.percolates()` never returns true. Either there's an issue with that method, or the rest of the code in the `while` loop needs to change something that it's not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the feedback. The true answer is that there is a chance that the grid fills up with numbers that don't actually percolate. Say a 2x2 grid looks like this:

| 1  2 |
| 2  1 |

then the program will never detect that any spaces are open so it will continue generating numbers for i, j, k forever.